# Style the first post in WP_Query differently

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a WP_Query loop that pulls the 4 most recent posts:

```
    <?php
    $featuredPosts = new WP_Query();
    $featuredPosts->query('showposts=4');
    while ($featuredPosts->have_posts()) : $featuredPosts->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="recentpost">

    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail ($_post->ID, 'small'); ?>

    <div class="titlerecent">
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    </div>

    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

What I want to do is modify this and style the first post in the loop different.  I don't just want to add a CSS class to it, I want to wrap it in a totally different `<div>`.

So I want the first post to be wrapped in `<div class="homefirstpost">` and then the remaining 3 post to be as above, inside the `<div class="recentpost">`.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
<?php
$isfirst = false;

$featuredPosts = new WP_Query();
$featuredPosts->query('showposts=4');
while ($featuredPosts->have_posts()) : $featuredPosts->the_post(); ?>

    <?php if ( ! $isfirst ): ?>
    <div class="homefirstpost">
        <?php $isfirst = true; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <div class="recentpost">
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail ($_post->ID, 'small'); ?>

    <div class="titlerecent">
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When your posts are wrapped in another container, you could use the `:first-child` selector for the first post. See [Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child) for details.

When your HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="featuredPosts">
    <div>First Post ...</div>
    <div>Next Post ...</div>
    <div>Next Post ...</div>
    <div>Next Post ...</div>
</div>
```

you can use CSS along these lines:

```
div#featuredPosts > div:first-child {
some special styles;
}
```